# Select2 and Bootstrap 3 CSS Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Select2 plugin in my Bootstrap 3 based project.
I cannot find a way to fix one problem. When I'm using select2 like a part of `.input-group` and selected value is long - it's broking structure. (I made some css to fit select2 into Bootstrap style but it's not affect `display:` style so I don't attaching it).

[**JS fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2rvn0ktj/)

When I'm using `.input-group` then it's changing children elements to `display: table-cell` but I cannot force elements to fit parent container. I cannot change `max-width:` of `.input-group` because it's not working. I did try to change `table-layout` but it's seems not working with elements different than `<table>`.

Any Ideas how can I fix that?
PS. I cannot add any additional CSS class to any of those elements.

Comment: Your jsfiddle is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the `dropdownAutoWith` option.

```
$('select').select2({
    dropdownAutoWidth: true
});
```

Here's a [fork](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyEstilles/rgnLy0r6/) of your Fiddle, with my answer applied.